# CSV values in Datatable Cell to textBoxes

Tags: vb.net, csv, datatable, code-behind

Fair beginner hence this question.

I have a datatable reading from MSSQL and one of the fields (Cells) is IP address's. Helpfully the coder has put them all in once cell as CSV :(

```
123.456.111.222, 4.56.78.23, 143.222.222.1
```

1. I need to display these on a page in a multiline textbox as single row entries.
2. I need to then re-read the entries back to the Single CSV Cell and update the Datatable they came from.

Its in VB but Ill take anything right now!

Thanks so much anyone. Been on this 6 hours now and just can't do it.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I need to display these on a page in a multiline textbox as single row entries.

If you have a single string and you want to split it into multiple tokens use `String.Split`:

```
Dim cellText = "123.456.111.222, 4.56.78.23, 143.222.222.1"
Dim allIPs As String() = cellText.Split({", "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

> 2. I need to then re-read the entries back to the Single CSV Cell and update the Datatable they came from.

If you want to do the opposite use `String.Join`:

```
Dim cellText As String = String.Join(", ", allIPs)
yourDataRow.SetField("ColumnName", cellText)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Here is the final code I used:

Dim allIPs As String() = IPcellText.Split({", "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

```
                TextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, allIPs)



                ' Re-read back
                Dim allips2 As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                For i As Integer = 0 To allIPs.Length - 1
                    allIPs(i) = allIPs(i).Trim()
                Next
                Dim ipList As String = String.Join(", ", allIPs)
                Response.Write(ipList)
```